# What is the usage of 'as' clause in the sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning and the function of 'as it has existed in practice' in below sentence?

'A criticism of democracy **as it has existed in practice** is that the power to vote for leaders is of peripheral importance in societies in which there are powerful vested interests that control the economy, the media, and other powerful areas.'

My questions are...
1. 'as it has existed in practice' is a clause that modifies the subject 'a criticism of democracy', right?

2. What is the meaning of that clause? (What does 'as' mean here? What does 'in practice'  means?)
3. The clause can be eliminated and still mean the same thing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The clause **as it has existed in practice** is modifying **democracy** in the example sentence. **as it has existed** cannot modify *a criticism* because it is obvious that the criticism is existing in practice. There are no extra words needed to define it. However, democracy is largely the set of rules or criteria existing on papers and then implemented in practice.

Ans 1. **"as it has existed in practice" is modifying democracy**.

Ans 2. ***The meaning of the clause: Democracy is being practiced in the form of power to vote for leaders.***

Ans 3. ***The clause is important but could have been better framed as "A criticism of democracy, as it has existed in practice, is that the power..."***

Answer (score 0):

It’s not actually a clause, but a preposition phrase introduced by the preposition *as*. The function of the PP is that of modifier of the noun *democracy*.

The preposition *as* has a meaning akin to *in the manner*, so we can paraphrase  the PP as *in the manner it has existed in practice*.

*In practice* means what actually happened, as opposed to what was meant or believed to happen.

Modifiers are always optional, and hence it is omissible with no change in the core meaning of the sentence as a whole.